# Copying the sources.list

Tags: apt-get, apt

Just installed Linux on another machine, a laptop.  It's the exact same distro and version on I have on my PC.

Wouldn't it be possible to copy the /etc/apt/sources.list from the PC to the laptop so I don't have to go hunting for all the ppa's I will end up adding anyway ?

Comment: Yes, do you have any issue with copying the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is generally possible. However note the following:

- If the .list files set the architecture via option like `[arch=amd64]`, then of course the target machine CPU (and OS version) should support (match) this architecture. However, this option is rarely used and in case of PC and laptop, both are likely the same `x86_64`/`amd64` anyway.
- APT usually only accepts repositories if the public GPG key has been added as trusted key. So likely you need to copy additional public keys from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` over to the new machine as well, or use [apt-key add](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-get)